# wxPython refresh frame

Tags: wxpython, refresh, frames

Title says it all.I can't find a way to do it... .Refresh() doens't do anything, other than crash the program.

The situation I'm in, is that I have a frame which is launched from the "main" frame. This frame makes changes to the "main" frame's menu bar and panel. What can I call to refresh the main frame, from the second frame?

Comment: Can you post some code / stack traces / errors?  Something more than "it doesn't work" is going to be required.  I use `Refresh()` on plenty of things and it works fine.

Comment: Well, to be quite honest, I have  no clue what to run. I was using .GetParent() to select the frame (the method is in a panel) but that selects the second frame, not the original one.

Comment: If your ancestry looks like this:  Frame1 > Frame2 > Panel then you can access Frame1 from Panel as `Panel.GrandParent`.  It may be enough to call Refresh once you have the right element.  It really depends a great deal on how your app is structured and what you're changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one could be done with pubsub. Have the second frame publish a message to the first frame telling it to refresh. I actually think you'll want to use Layout() though. That's what I usually use when I remove or add visible elements. You shouldn't need to Refresh() a menu when removing items from it. At least, the example in the wxPython demo doesn't do that.